# MYSQL Connection through vscode

Tags: mysql

Initializing SQL tools service for the mssql extension.

when testing connection facing this issue

client otion 'pooling.maxIdle Time' does not support value 'NaN'.

I just tried to test connection and facing this error. Not able to connect to the server